# Laravel is returning a XSRF-COOKIE decrypted as cookie

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm following the default setup as in the Sanctum documentation, i make a request o csrf cookie route so Laravel triggers the Cookies and set to the request the `XSRF-TOKEN`, but the documentation says:

> Laravel stores the current CSRF token in an encrypted XSRF-TOKEN cookie that is included with each response generated by the framework. You can use the cookie value to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN request header.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

This is the code of frontend i retrieve the Cookie every time and send in the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header

```js
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_NAME)

  console.log(Cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: authToken ? `Bearer ${authToken}` : '',
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': Cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    }
  }
})
```

Of course, this is executed everytime a request is made, so here is the relevant console log:

[image]

As you can see, for some reason Laravel is sending randomly a decrypted cookie in plain text, and some times a encrypted one.

Of course, it's important that only the encrypted cookie should be returned because the header `X-XSRF-TOKEN` is decrypted on backend every time, as you can see in `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`:

```php
/**
 * Get the CSRF token from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function getTokenFromRequest($request)
{
    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        try {
            $token = CookieValuePrefix::remove($this->encrypter->decrypt($header, static::serialized()));
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            $token = '';
        }
    }

    return $token;
}
```

So, does anyone has any idea why Laravel is returning to me a randomly encrypted and decrypted csrf token, instead of only the encrypted one? Or even weirder, it's returning both tokens, in each request one type?